# Why does contentEditable element reject the Enter key?

Tags: html, keypress, contenteditable, keydown

I'm using an application that embeds IE control to show content. I change that content to contain a `<div contentEditable="True">Hello World</div>` element. This works well and I can edit the content of this div, but pressing Enter is rejected with a beep.

When I add a textarea element to that page the Enter key works and I can add lines, but not in the contentEditable element.

When I attach event to that element I see that pressing the Enter key triggers a keyDown event, but not a keyPress.

Anyone has an idea what might cause it?

Thanks,
splintor

Comment: Does the document work correctly (as expected) in a normal browser?

Comment: Yes - in a normal browser it works perfectly OK.

Comment: my solution works for me, you give hint to solve my problem for that upvote

Answer (score 0):

Most HTML elements ignore whitespace. Including a \r or \n in any DIV or similar element is just ignored.

Comment: But when done in a separate browser window, there is no problem. The browser translate <enter> pressings to <br>s.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked it in IE and Firefox it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Some where else you attach the keydown event to document.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', handle, false);
```

remove it or add keydown event to editable to stopPropagation.

```
$('#target').keydown(function(e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
});
```